# Is it possible to submit a form in asp.net without any server controls

Tags: asp.net, html, forms, controls, submit

Hai guys,
       I had this doubt for a long time now. Now being a part of stackoverflow i ve decided to ask it... Consider form without **Runat="server"** and it contains two html text boxes and a html button all without **Runat="server"**, now my is it possible to submit this form and i have to insert the values in my DB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can read the values from those controls by using

```
var valueFromHtmlControl = Request.Form["Control-Identified"]
```

Comment: I've been a classic-asp developer for more than 3 years in past. In fact that's where I started. I still love it! Now an asp.net developer

Comment: @geek if i do like this through out my application i ll have more number of pages know what can be done for this...

Comment: @geek: wiohoo. i've been an asp.net developer for like 6 months only !!  , well C# for like 1 year before that...which kinda helped :)

Comment: Your comment reminded me of old good days in a flash of second. :)

Answer (score 3):

If your "HTML button" is a `<input type="submit" />` element, clicking it will indeed cause the `<form>` to be posted. However, it will not raise any `Click` events, since there is no `Button` object associated with the HTML button you have clicked.

In your `Page_Load()` method (or similar) you will be able to retrieve the posted values using the `Request.Form` collection. Example with text input has `name="myField"`:

```
string postedVal = Request.Form["myField"];
```

Comment: i just noticed ur answer is 2 mins earlier than Geek :) so +1 for u too :)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely - this can lead to some unwanted effects, such as cross site request forgery, which is worth looking out for:

[Wikipedia ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)